# Matrix presentation of objects in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I need to represent a list of objects as a matrix. The size of the matrix is always 16x16.

The object contains only 3 fields:

```
private byte deviceAddress;
private byte register;
private byte[] data;
```

Inside each cell should be displayed only value of **data** field and also each cell should be **updatable**.

I tried to implement some converter with `new DataTable` as returned object, but each time when I perform the conversion, the datagrid flickers and draws new columns and rows (this is not acceptable).

Maybe exist some way to write datatemplate to represent this?

Expected result should be like on picture:

[image: Result]

Comment: It should display value of `data` or `deviceAdress`? Because data is an byte array, so, how to you want to display it? Also, by the picture it looks a lot like an address

Comment: you need to either create two VMs for the whole matrix (one for cell, one for row) or use a uniformgrid as the itemspaneltemplate of an itemscontrol (each cell would represent one VM with a bindable data)... it depends on your code

Comment: @Magnetron it should display value of data. It was just example.

Comment: Do you want to display 256 `TextBox`es simultaneously, or do you want something more performant, e.g. like a `DataGrid`, which displays only one `TextBox` at a time?

Comment: @FrankM I need smth that allows me to display one field of list which contain 256 elements with predefined structure like on picture and with ability to bind selected item to some property. Not more:) I'm stacked with choosing of needed element and way to solve this issue, because for me is not regular task:)

Comment: @AlexEntin you didn't say how data, which is an array, should be displayed in a single cell. Are you suming all the values? Are you concateneting? Are you using a custom formula? Also, how do you expect to update the value if is its a sum, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your data is stored in a class like this:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public byte deviceAddress { get; set; }
    public byte register { get; set; }
    public byte[] data { get; set; }
}
```

and you have a list of 256 such objects

```
public List<MyItem> MyMatrix { get; set; }
```

you could use an `ItemsControl` with a `UniformGrid` as ItemsPanel:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyMatrix}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="16"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding data,
                     Converter={StaticResource yourDataToStringConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you need to be able to select an item, use a ListBox instead of an ItemsControl.

Note that the Window's DataContext must be set to an instance of a class with the `MyMatrix` property, and you need an implementation of IValueConverter that converts `data` to an appropriate string representation (or whatever else).

Comment: Why the nested ItemsControl (with the outer one without ItemsPanel)? `YouMatrix` could just be a collection of 256 elements. How `data` is supposed to be visualized isn't clear from the question.

Comment: I suggested a list of list. I supposed that Matrix is a list of object and every object contains data property. It wants to be just a point to start from. The outer is the default (the StackPanel), the inner an UniformGrid with 16 columns.

Comment: That's a lot more complicated than necessary. A single ItemsControl is sufficient.

Comment: I don't understand how can be created the matrix structure with a single itemsControl. He needs to use a data template for the row i suppose.

Comment: By using a UniformGrid with 16 columns in a single ItemsControl. When there are 256 elements in the source collection, the UniformGrid  will have 16 columns and 16 rows.

Comment: Yes in this case, yes. But i've understood that the data are in a list of object (16 object). However it's not really clear

Comment: "a list of objects as a matrix" and "object contains only 3 fields". So data is in a cell, not a row.

Comment: Probably i've misunderstanded...if you thik it's unclear i'll remove the answer.

Comment: "Probably i've misunderstanded" maybe. Until OP clarifies that, you should try to post the most simple solution, i.e. a single ItemsSource. Should I edit your answer?

Comment: @Clemens do you know, it was the first thing i wrote :D, after i changed interpretation.

Comment: @Clemens & Babbillumpa Thanks! It's working like I expect, but with only one problem:) I don't know how to add headers to rows and columns. Maybe it's a little impudent, but I wanted to ask the easiest way to add static headers (for rows and columns) like on picture

Comment: @AlexEntin i suggest you to open another question for that.