# ItemsControl with row and column headers WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I need to represent updatable list `ObservableCollection<RegisterBean> listOfRegisters` of objects `RegisterBean` as matrix with row and column headers Object contain 3 properties:

```
byte deviceAddress;
byte register;
byte[] data;
```

And only one property ***data*** should be displayed.
The expected result is like on image:
[image: Expected]

I reached this structure with usual datagrid but the problem was to update it because I used a converter with `new DataTable()` as a returned value. This is not correct because it flickers and rerenders all objects.

I asked for a help yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381683/matrix-presentation-of-objects-in-datagrid/51382447?noredirect=1#comment89740208_51382447). And this solution is working:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding listOfRegisters}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <UniformGrid Columns="16"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Data, Converter={StaticResource ByteToStringValueConverter}}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But I didn't understand how to change the structure of usercontrol and to add headers. The result of the solution with `itemscontrol`:
[image: result with usercontrol]

Thanks!

**UPD:**
The headers should be static without any sorting and stuff like that

Comment: `ItemsControl` doesn't have columns. `GridView` does (e.g. `ListView` uses it).

Comment: So you have a mostly working `DataGrid` with a minor update problem and instead of trying to fix the update problem, you decide to downgrade your whole infrastructure to an `ItemsControl`, then you wonder how to improve the `ItemsControl` to the point of behaving mostly like a `DataGrid`?

Comment: @grek40 you 100% right, but I was stacked and thought that this is way to solve my problem. If you have any suggestion - you are welcome :)

Comment: Can you give a specific example of one `RegisterBean` object with concrete values for `deviceAddress`, `register` and `data` (multiple bytes please) and explain in which row/column it would appear, what would be displayed and how it would be edited?

Comment: @grek40 This is a representation of device registers from `0x00` to `0xFF`. The length could be 1 or 2 bytes (depends on the device). Each cell displays `Data` property of the `RegisterBean`. For example: `deviceAddress = 0x60, register 0x5A, data = { 0xFF }`. DeviceAddress is needed only for binding of selected item and to use it later (I don't show it on this concrete view). Register value gives to me position of concrete bean in datagrid (`0x5A` will be at the intersection of row `0x5` and column `A`). Data should be displayed like on picture as cell value.

Comment: @AlexEntin Are the headers static ?

Comment: @Babbillumpa yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I start saying that probably, checking what's wrong with DataGrid would be better and that is not necessary to re-write Controls, but if you still want to use the `ItemsControl` ...

Supposing that there are two collections (ColHeaders & RowHeaders) in your ViewModel that contains your Headers you can add two other panels that hold headers..

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Column Headers -->
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding ColHeaders}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" Width="30" Height="30"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding listOfRegisters}">
       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <UniformGrid Columns="16"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
               </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding Data, Converter={StaticResource ByteToStringValueConverter}}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <!-- RowHeaders -->
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RowHeaders}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" Width="30" Height="30"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

I also sized the TextBlocks and the TextBoxes in order to align everything.

Comment: I also prefer datagrid, maybe later I'll try to find solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just add a Grid around it, like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Col 0"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Col 1"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Col 2"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Row 0"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Row 1"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="Row 2"/>
    </Grid>
    <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Content="00"/>
        <Button Content="01"/>
        <Button Content="02"/>
        <Button Content="10"/>
        <Button Content="11"/>
        <Button Content="12"/>
        <Button Content="20"/>
        <Button Content="21"/>
        <Button Content="22"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This gives nice column and row headers around a UniformGrid...?